# Add columns to pandas Dataframe on different conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
'a': [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1], 
'b': [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1], 
'c': [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],
'rate': [0,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.24,0.27,0.3,0.4]})
```

a,b,c are my channels and I am adding another column that shows the sum of row wise totals of these channels by writing:

```
data['total'] = data.a + data.b + data.c

data

    a   b   c   rate    total
1   1   0   0   0.10    1
2   0   1   0   0.11    1 
3   0   0   1   0.12    1
4   1   1   0   0.24    2
5   1   0   1   0.27    2
6   0   1   1   0.30    2
7   1   1   1   0.40    3
```

I would like to work on data where total = 1 and total = 2

```
reduced = data[(data.a == 1) & (data.total == 2)]
print(reduced)

     a  b  c  rate  total
  4  1  1  0  0.24      2
  5  1  0  1  0.27      2
```

I would like to add columns to this reduced dataframe that looks like this:

```
      a  b  c  rate  total  prob_a  prob_b  prob_c
   4  1  1  0  0.24      2     0.1    0.11    0
   5  1  0  1  0.27      2     0.1     0      0.12
```

In the first row of the reduced data-frame, prob_c is 0 since C is absent ( ABC => 110). In the second row of the reduced data-frame, prob_b is 0 since B is absent (ABC => 101)

where,

```
# Channel a alone occurs (ABC => 100)
prob_a = data['rate'][(data.a == 1) & (data.total == 1)]

# Channel b alone occurs (ABC => 010)
prob_b = data['rate'][(data.b == 1) & (data.total == 1)]

# Channel c alone occurs (ABC => 001)
prob_c = data['rate'][(data.c == 1) & (data.total == 1)]
```

I tried this:

```
reduced['prob_a'] = data['rate'][(data.a == 1) & (data.total == 1)]
reduced['prob_b'] = data['rate'][(data.b == 1) & (data.total == 1)]
reduced['prob_c'] = data['rate'][(data.c == 1) & (data.total == 1)]
print(reduced)
```

which results in this output:

```
   a  b  c  rate  total  prob_a  prob_b  prob_c
4  1  1  0  0.24      2     NaN     NaN     NaN
5  1  0  1  0.27      2     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
reduced['prob_a'] = data.loc[(data.a == 1) & (data.total == 1),'rate'].values[0]
reduced['prob_b'] = data.loc[(data.b == 1) & (data.total == 1),'rate'].values[0]
reduced['prob_c'] = data.loc[(data.c == 1) & (data.total == 1),'rate'].values[0]

reduced[['prob_a','prob_b','prob_c']]=reduced[['prob_a','prob_b','prob_c']].mul(reduced[['a','b','c']].eq(1).values)
reduced
Out[698]: 
   a  b  c  rate  total  prob_a  prob_b  prob_c
4  1  1  0  0.24      2     0.1    0.11    0.00
5  1  0  1  0.27      2     0.1    0.00    0.12
```

Answer (score 2):

Break it into two steps

**One**
Calculate Probabilities

```
probs = data.query('a + b + c == 1').pipe(
    lambda d: d.drop('rate', 1).T.dot(d.rate)
)

probs

a    0.10
b    0.11
c    0.12
dtype: float64
```

**How it works**
Get just the total equals to one rows:

```
data.query('a + b + c == 1')

   a  b  c  rate
1  1  0  0  0.10
2  0  1  0  0.11
3  0  0  1  0.12
```

`pipe` allows us to pipeline the results into function.  From the result above, I want to dot product the columns `a`, `b`, `c` with the column `rate`.  The `lambda` via the `pipe` allows me to do that.

**More Generalized Approach**

```
df = data.copy()
rate = df.pop('rate')
mask = df.sum(1) == 1
probs = df[mask].T.dot(rate[mask])

probs
```

**Two**
The Rest

```
data.join(
    data.drop('rate', 1).mul(probs).add_prefix('prob_')
).query('a + b + c == 2 and a == 1')

   a  b  c  rate  prob_a  prob_b  prob_c
4  1  1  0  0.24     0.1    0.11    0.00
5  1  0  1  0.27     0.1    0.00    0.12
```

Comment: hey, can u please explain the first step - especially the lambda expression.

Comment: The example in the question talks about 3 channels at a time. But in general, if I have "N" channels (a,b,c,d, ... z) ,  how do i write a function that gives me the probabilities for all possible combinations of pairs. For example, if I have 5 channels - A,B,C,D,E. I need 5c2 = 10 rows in my output where each row shows presence of only 2 channels at a time.

Comment: I added a more general approach for you